# Free Mission Control-like Windows app

Tags: windows, gratis, window-manager

Looking for an app for a friend on Windows that emulates macOS’s [Mission Control](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mission_Control_(macOS)), *more specifically* the [Spaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spaces_(software)) functionality that is also present in many Linux window managers.

The app needs to be free as in beer; bonus if it’s also free as in freedom.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The basic functionality of having multiple desktops is built into the Windows API since a long time. It's mostly unknown, but [documented](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687105(v=vs.85).aspx).

[SysInternals Desktops](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/desktops) is a tool to manage such Desktops.

- it's provided by Microsoft for free (not open source)
- it works (only) on Windows

It'll show up in the Tray and create a new desktop when needed:

[image: Desktops system tray]

Answer (score 1):

Windows 10 now has the new "Task View" feature built in. You can switch between desktops/spaces by clicking the new icon in the Taskbar or use the "Win-Tab" feature.

With a smart trackpad you can also switch between desktops by using a three finger swipe left/right. I prefer this with Laptops especially. You may have to turn on the feature in Windows Settings.

Answer (score 0):

[VirtuaWin](http://virtuawin.sourceforge.net/) is no cost (gratis) and open source under GPL (freedom).

Its features include:

- an N x M array of desktops, you choose the size
- assign names and keyboard shortcuts to each workspace
- assign a given window to one or all desktops
- move windows between desktops with keyboard or menu item
- define rules to open a given window or application in a given desktop

Answer (score 0):

If it is for personal use, you can use [Dexpot](http://dexpot.de/?id=download) for free. I use this at home and it is excellent. A commercial single-use licence is approx 25€.

It is easy to move between desktops, have apps follow you (or not). In fact, it has a lot more power than I currently use.